# XCode + React-native: "Bundle React Native code and images" build phase taking too long

Tags: node.js, xcode, react-native, build, macos-sierra

There's something going wrong building my RN app. The "Bundle React Native code and images" is taking too long.
It takes about 10 minutes to finish this only task!

[Here's the complete build log](https://pastebin.com/d5g5KCkr)

It seems that bundling JS is taking too long to finish.

Additional Info:

- MacOS Sierra v10.12.5 (Mac mini)
- XCode v8.3.3
- react-native v0.42.3
- npm v3.10.10
- node v6.11.0
- watchman v4.7.0

I've tried to uninstall and install `watchman` using homebrew. But the problem continues.

Comment: i have this issue too, any progress?

Comment: i think you should add the packages information too

Answer (score 0):

I know this question's posted 4 years ago, but I've been looking around a lot to find a solution and I found out the reason for my particular project.

---

I had the same issue where my build process would hang at the "Bundle React Native code and images" phase.

Then I removed **@react-native-firebase/firestore** from my packages and then my total build time dropped from 2007s (33 mins) to 450s (7.5 mins) . I guess the sub-dependencies were HUGE.